# Can one use an adjective as a noun in French?

Tags: grammaire

This is common in Latin, as there are genders for adjectives therefore "stultus pecuniam semper laudat," means "a foolish [man] always praises money." We know that this is a man as the adjective **stultus** is masculine. Therefore, could we say in French "Un beau veut toujours d'être sur son trente et un" instead of "Un bel homme veut toujours d'être sur son trente et un?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Un sot trouve toujours un plus sot qui l'admire.* -- Nicholas Boileau

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many adjectives including *beau* can be substantivized but the resulting sentence is slightly odd in your example.

*Un beau veut...* is not really idiomatic although *un [vieux beau](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vieux_beau) veut...* would be.

Comment: @Qu'arrhesrententsanshune I relied on https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substantive#Verb I pick the most used, thanks!

Comment: I'd certainly choose *substantivized* here too. Or "an adjective can be a substantive" for some metagrammar.